# Chrome extension Native Messaging alternatives on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension

I am porting my chrome extension from Win/MacOS to Android. One problem I see is that Native Messaging is not supported on Android. Is there any other way to communicate between local application and extension on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSocket (https://github.com/hakobera/Simple-WebSocket-Client) solves my problem.

Comment: Which library did you use on Android side? and which on server side? just to have an idea for the compatibility issues/